# How to reimpement unique id's to records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I wrongly mass uploaded a spreadsheet of data to a website.  When I did this it assigned each row a unique id.

The problem arises when trying to create relations between the records.  For ex: the restaurant "Foo" has 5 deals.  But there is nothing linking each record together, other than the name Foo.

Should I just completely rebuild the app or is there a way that I can Assign all "Foo's" a unique id?

Comment: Two solutions. First, if you are just seeding your data into the app, it may be faster to remove al data from your app, fix the issue where you didn't assign Foreign Keys, and re-add your data. Second, if you can't remove all data, E.G. Production, you could write a script to fix your data for you. You would still want to fix the part of your app that skewed the data.

Comment: `Foo` sounds like a unique id to me, but I don't know what stupid requirements rails may impose on your data.